# why ConcurrentModificationException is not thrown

Tags: java, exception, collections

When you Iterate a collection using Java 1.5 modern for loop and remove some element 
concurrentmodifuicationexception is thrown.

But when I run follwoing code it does not throw any exception:

```
    public static void main(String a []){
          Set<String> strs = new HashSet<String>();
          strs.add("one");
          strs.add("two");
          strs.add("three);

          for(String str : strs){
                   if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("two"){
                          strs.remove(str);
                   }
          }  
    }
```

Above code does not throw ConcurrentModificationException. But when I use any such for loop in my web application service method it always throws one. Why? I am sure no two threads are accessing the collection when it runs in service method  So what causes the difference in two scenarios where it is thrown in one and not in the other?

Comment: [Gives me one](http://ideone.com/o73eW)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when running your code (after fixing the few typos).

The only scenarios where you would not get a `ConcurrentModificationException` are:

- if the item that you remove is not in the set, see example below:
- if you remove the last iterated item (which is not necessarily the last added item in the case of a HashSet)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> strs = new HashSet<String>();
    strs.add("one");
    strs.add("two");
    strs.add("three");

    for (String str : strs) {
        //note the typo: twos is NOT in the set
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("twos")) {
            strs.remove(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 If you remove the last element iterated, you won't get a CME.

Comment: This runs fine. ;)         Set<String> strs = new HashSet<String>();
        strs.add("one");
        for (String str : strs) {
            strs.remove(str);
        }

Comment: ok will try with the list so that itration order remains predictable

Comment: what say? ya sorry that was my bad to do a type

Comment: @assylias:
just tried with list so that I know I am not removing the last element and it is not throwing one. Did you try it in simple main method? I am using JRE 6

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan Post your example.

Comment: @assylias:here it is : public static void main(String[] args) { List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>(); strs.add("one"); strs.add("two"); strs.add("three"); for (String str : strs) { //note the typo: twos is NOT in the set if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("two")) { strs.remove(str); } } System.out.println(strs.size()); }  I am doing it in eclipse ide

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan This is a border case - the enhanced for loop is equivalent to using an iterator. The ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when `it.next()` is called. In the case you describe, after having removed "two", the loop calls `it.hasNext()`, which compared the number of iteration (2) to the current size of the list (now 2 since you removed "two"). So the loop terminates and `next()` is not called.

Comment: I suggest you write the code with a normal iterator and debug it step by step to understand what happens under the hood. If you try to remove "one" you will get a CME.

Comment: @assylias:yes it does .thanks for making my understanding(misunderstanding!!) clear. will try your metod using iteerator as well